# RMagick weird green gif when setting image_type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, rmagick

So I got this following code trying to convert a png to gif in ruby using RMagick, but got some weird green stuff on some part of the image.

```
require 'RMagick'
include Magick
img = Magick::Image.read(pngPath.open).first
//if comment out the following line, there is no problem
img.image_type=PaletteMatteType
img.transparent("#00FF00")
img.write(gifPath)
```

PS: how to change the depth to 8 or 16 and How to change colors to 256? The default for depth and colors are 8 and 256 right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most RMagick methods *return* the new image rather than *modifying* it in-place; some methods have `!` versions for modifying things in place (such as [`scale`](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#scale) and [`scale!`](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#scale_bang)) but some don't (such as [`quantize`](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#quantize)).

In particular, [`transparent`](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#transparent) returns the new image:

> `img.transparent(color, opacity=TransparentOpacity) -> image`
>   [...]
>   **Returns**
>   A new image

So just saying `img.transparent("#00FF00")` creates a new image with the desired transparency and then throws it away because you are ignoring the return value.

Also, the usual way to drop something down to a smaller palette is to use [`quantize`](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#quantize).

I think you want something like this:

```
img = Magick::Image.read(pngPath.open).first
img = img.transparent('#00FF00')
img = img.quantize(256)
img.write(gifPath)
```

Works for me at least.

Comment: Solved! Thanks for the perfect answer! Now my gif doesn't have these weird green areas, but still ugly, with patches of some small black areas on which used to be transparent areas, and not nearly as good as the original png file

Comment: @randomor: The black areas are probably from the quantization, you could try doing the `.quantize` before the `.transpartent`.

Comment: What you did is pure magick! Solved, Really appreciate that. BTW, how do you know? I'm a noob.

Comment: @randomor: Experience (i.e. making mistaeks).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the defaults by I would change a couple of thing:

if you require RMagick, there is no need to include Magick afterwards, I think you can delete this line.

Constants should be prefixed by Magick::, so it should probably be `Magick::PaletteMatteType`

the transparent method takes 2 arguments, the first one being the color that you want to make transparent, and the second is the kind of transparency. I think Gif knows only one kind, but anyway, try

```
img.transparent("#00FF00", Magick::TransparentOpacity)
```

Comment: Thanks, added that, but is still having the green areas in picture, maybe it's hardware?